# Duplicate meta tags for the same page

Tags: php

I am getting warnings in Webmaster Tools to say that I have duplicate title and description meta tags. However the 2 pages listed are actually the same page, one with the `.php` extension and one without the `.php` extension.

http://www.w-co.co.uk/3d-led-lightboxes.php
and
http://www.w-co.co.uk/3d-led-lightboxes

I have tried using a canonical link in the head of the one with the `.php` extension:

```
link rel="canonical" href="http://www.w-co.co.uk/3d-led-lightboxes.php"/
```

But I am still getting the same error (it's been there for months now).

Any ideas how I can clear this duplicate error?

Comment: **You have 2 pages with same Doctype, head, html, meta, title, style,body and contents,! thats why webmaster tool is unable to indetify which on is diffrent** ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best shot here is using .htaccess to 'redirect' users from .php to the friendly page, like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.w-co.co.uk$1
```